# youtube-api - Event on timeupdate

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to raise an event when IFrame embedded YouTube reach a specific frame?

I am looking for something similar to HTML5 player `timeupdate` event.

I am not looking for using a `setInterval` to check the current position (as suggested in [Youtube API event on a specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175367/youtube-api-event-on-a-specified-time)), I would like to know if there is a native API to support such feature.

Comment: I have built a player using the YouTube API and I used the `requestAnimationFrame()` function to create a loop which constantly checks `getElapsedTime()` to update the player's track position. Although you said you don't want to use `setInterval`, it is this 'polling' method which I believe is how you would be able to check if the track has reached a specific frame.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as there is no such [event](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events) within the iFrame API. Although it is not directly possible you could try something like this, if you need a video to end a specific point for example you can use load parameters to do this, like so.

```
loadVideoById({'videoId': 'bHQqvYy5KYo',
           'startSeconds': 5,
           'endSeconds': 60,
           'suggestedQuality': 'large'});
```

After that you would hook into the `onStateChange` event and depends on what you want to do continue playing, ask a question about up to the timeframe etc.

However if this is designed to be used on mobile you must consider as per most mobile browsers (references says iOS, i think android does too).

> "Warning: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at the user’s expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically in Safari on iOS — the user always initiates playback."

So if a video ends or pauses you can not pragmatically restart/resume the video, the user must always do it.